# Twitter Bootstrap responsive .hidden-desktop class not working in IE7 with respond.js

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap

I added respond.js to support media queries in IE7-8. For some reason, the "hidden-desktop" class is working in IE8 but not in IE7. Note that other responsive Bootstrap classes are working in IE7 though, such as "visible-desktop".

Does any have an idea why?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to the following definition in bootstrap-responsive.css:

.hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }

IE7 does not support display: inherit.

Comment: way to go twitter. (on a side note, i have a feel the twitter guys are less and less concerned with ie7)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a solution to this for IE7 even though it doesn't support inherit.  Please see this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18854835/1370033